# CanCan, restrict view action only for resources with a certain tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, devise, cancan

I have a rails app that uses devise and cancan.

I have a Post resource that users (signed in or not) can read:

```
user ||= User.new
if user.has_role? :admin
  can :manage, :all
else
  can :read, Post
end
```

I use a tagging system to categorize posts and I want to create a tag called "restricted" whose show action is restricted to signed in users.

Here is how I call a post with the restricted tag:

```
@post.tags.find_by_name("restricted")
```

Should I use an if statement in the controller or somehow restrict the action in the ability.rb file?

Comment: I'm not sure understanding your question, but you can restrict action in controller, example: `load_and_authorize_resource only: [:new,:create]`

Comment: @KienThanh, yes but I need to restrict the show action only if the post has a certain tag, not all the show action. For example I have a post tagged "foo" and a post tagged "restricted". A logged in user should be able to perform the show action for both posts, a non logged in user should be allovwed to see the "foo" post but not the "restricted" one

Comment: maybe you can add below `can :read, Post` this: `cannot :read, Post.join(:tags).where(tags: { name: "restricted" } )`

Comment: @KienThanh, it looks like I cannot do that from the ability model: undefined method `join' for #<Class:0x007fdb51b67a90>

Comment: how about this: `cannot :read, Post, tags: { name: "restricted" }`

Comment: so i will post answer, please accepted if it helped you, thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can add below `can :read, Post` this code:

```
cannot :read, Post, tags: { name: "restricted" }
```

This restrict user not logged in can not read Posts have tag's name is "restricted".